# trying to mask 2D numpy arrays based on values in one column

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array:

```
[[    6.           105.             2.             8.09841881]
[    6.           105.             4.             9.34220351]
[    6.           105.             6.             9.97663435]
[    6.          1001.             2.             9.57108242]
[    6.          1001.             4.            12.22355794]
[    6.          1001.             6.            13.57295942]
[   12.          1001.             2.            12.37474466]
[   12.          1001.             4.            17.45334004]
[   12.          1001.             6.            19.88499289]
[   18.          1007.             2.            16.09076561]
[   18.          1007.             4.            23.43742275]
[   18.          1007.             6.            27.73041646]]
```

And I have tried to extract only the rows with the first element being a six via

```
print ma.MaskedArray(a, mask=(np.ones_like(a)*(a[:,0]==6.0)).T)
```

which I got from the question " [mask a 2D numpy array based on values in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625744/mask-a-2d-numpy-array-based-on-values-in-one-column)". However, I get

```
File "./Prova.py", line 170, in <module>
print ma.MaskedArray(a, mask=(np.ones_like(a)*(a[:,0]==6.0)).T)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,4) (12)
```

do you have a clue of why this doesn't work?

The question might be stupid, but please bear with me since I just started programming python. :-)

Comment: You might need to insert a `np.newaxis` into your mask.

Comment: What would that do, and how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting up some test data to work on:

```
>>> a = np.arange(12*4).reshape((12,4))
```

First, we "allocate" space for our mask array:

```
>>> mask = np.empty(a.shape,dtype=bool)
```

Now we can't assign into it from the first column of `a == 6` directly because they're not the proper shape:

```
>>> mask[:,:] = a[:,0] == 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,4) (12)
```

But we can broadcast our first column of `a` up to the correct shape by simply inserting a newaxis so that it becomes a 2-D array:

```
>>> mask[:,:] = (a[:,0] == 6)[:,np.newaxis]
```

As we can see, our mask is now correct.

```
>>> mask
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Now we just make our masked array and sit back and enjoy :).

```
>>> ma.MaskedArray(a,mask=mask)
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- --]
 [20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27]
 [28 29 30 31]
 [32 33 34 35]
 [36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 43]
 [44 45 46 47]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: I don't believe the `.T` does anything, since the first line is a 1d array.

Comment: It keeps not working. I get:
      File "./Prova.py", line 171, in <module>
        mask = (np.ones_like(a)*(a[:,0]==6.0)).T
    ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,4) (12)

Comment: @FerdinandoRandisi -- See my update.  It seems to be working now.

Comment: @askewchan -- You're right.  I wasn't trying too hard to parse that expression to figure out what was going on.  Ultimately, it was a bit too compact for my blood.

Comment: It does work now! One last question though: what about the ones_like? Is it necessary?

Comment: @FerdinandoRandisi -- I don't have a `ones_like` in my solution, so apparently not ;-)

Comment: Yeah, often I wish that if `a.ndim = 1`, then `a.T` would return `a[...,np.newaxis]`, but then `a.T.T` wouldn't be `a`.