# remove certain elements from numpy array without destroying the structure

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array as below, I want to remove all zeros.

```
 a = [[ 5  2  0  9  4]
 [ 2  0  9  4  2]
 [ 0  9  4  2  6]
 [ 9  4  2  6  8]
 [ 4  2  6  8  0]
 [ 2  6  8  0  3]
 [ 6  8  0  3 11]
 [ 8  0  3 11  7]
 [ 0  3 11  7  1]
 [ 3 11  7  1  5]
 [11  7  1  5 21]
 [ 7  1  5 21  8]
 [ 1  5 21  8  0]
 [ 5 21  8  0 18]
 [21  8  0 18 12]
 [ 8  0 18 12  3]
 [ 0 18 12  3  9]]
```

What I want after removing all zeros is as below:

```
 b = [[ 5  2  9  4]
 [ 2  9  4  2]
 [ 9  4  2  6]
 [ 9  4  2  6  8]
 [ 4  2  6  8]
 [ 2  6  8  3]
 [ 6  8  3 11]
 [ 8  3 11  7]
 [ 3 11  7  1]
 [ 3 11  7  1  5]
 [11  7  1  5 21]
 [ 7  1  5 21  8]
 [ 1  5 21  8]
 [ 5 21  8 18]
 [21  8 18 12]
 [ 8 18 12  3]
 [18 12  3  9]]
```

I tried `a[a>0]` but it returned a 1D array: `[ 5  2  9  4  2  9  4  2  9  4  2  6  9  4  2  6  8  4  2  6  8  2  6  8  3 6  8  3 11  8  3 11  7  3 11  7  1  3 11  7  1  5 11  7  1  5 21  7  1  5 21  8  1  5 21  8  5 21  8 18 21  8 18 12  8 18 12  3 18 12  3  9]`. I wonder is there any command like this `a[a>0,axis=1]` to remove all the zeros without destroying its structure?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15773628/2666859

Comment: Not exactly the same... That question/answer is about [how to mask elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773570/trying-to-mask-2d-numpy-arrays-based-on-values-in-one-column/15773628), not how to remove elements.

Comment: Numpy arrays _have_ to have consistent dimensions, along a specific axis all sub-arrays need to have the same length

Comment: Would a list of arrays be okay as output?

Comment: Your result doesn't have the same structure as the original array.  You start with a rectangular array, (N,5).  You end up with a ragged list of lists (or object array of lists or arrays). That 1d array is the most efficient result.

Comment: @Divakar If the median of the subarrays of the list can be directly calculated, that would be great. It looks like I can not further speed up the rolling median issue.

Comment: @HuanianZhang Does the input array contain positive elements (zero or more) only?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, all zeros and positive elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result array cannot be a numpy array, because its shape is not constant. Therefore a possible solution would be doing it the standard pythonic way:

```
b = [row[row>0] for row in a]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But I have a following silly question. How could I calculate the median each subarray of b? I use `np.median(b)`, but it failed.

Comment: `[np.median(c) for c in b]`

Comment: Try this: `map(np.median, b)`

Comment: Whoa, @DomTomCat beat me by 19 seconds! I think both solutions work, though.

Comment: map and list comprehension are essentially the same - just different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to remove zeros if there's exactly the same numbers of zeros in each column. Note, in your example this is not (yet) possible.

```
b=np.hstack([y.reshape((len(y),1)) for y in [x[x>0] for x in [a[:,i] for i in range(a.shape[1])]]])
```

Comment: Actually my real data might have different number of zeros in each subarray. Sorry for the confusion. I try to implement this as efficient as possible because it is one part of my rolling median calculation function. Thanks a lot.